# scientific report two columns

Tags: two-column, document-classes

While looking for something on this site I accidentally found a document class which is perfect for a scientific report with two columns layout.

Unfortunately I forgot its name. Could someone point me out the document classes which implements two column layout without using `multicol` packages?

Comment: Article is one such class. `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some special classes primarily for paper submissions which offer a two-columned text body with easy float placement.

- [achemso](http://ctan.org/pkg/achemso)
- [elsarticle](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle)
- [revtex4-1](http://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1)
- …

There are probably some more which I don't remember at the moment. And I'm not sure if these classes are good for general use and documents that go beyond a certain number of pages.

Answer (score 16):

All the standard document classes have this - `article`, `book` and `report`. Just add the `twocolumn` option to the document class. For example, `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`. Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Although these document classes also support the use `\twocolumn`, the document option is preferred. For more on mixing columns (for say 1-column abstract in a 2-column document), see the [appropriately named TeX FAQ entry](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs).